# Can I configure pam_ldap without configuring nss?

Tags: ldap, pam, nss

On my servers I have my system users provisioned with Chef and have no desire to expose any additional users to these machines. I would however like to utilize `pam` for the authentication backend for my `monit` dashboard.

Do I need to set up `libnss-ldapd` to make `pam_ldap` work? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way. Would it really matter if I set up `nss` if `/etc/pam.d/common-*` don't use `pam_ldap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what flavor of `pam_ldap` we're talking about. You didn't mention an OS, but from the `libnss-ldapd` I can gather that we're talking about some flavor of Debian.

`libpam-ldap` and `libpam-ldapd` are two separate beasts and both implement pam_ldap.so. The ldapd flavor has a dependency on nslcd (not `libnss-ldapd`), which can be used without enabling the NSS component. I don't recall if nslcd has a hard dependency for `libnss-ldapd`, but even so it will only get referenced if you add "ldap" to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. You needn't worry about it somehow doing something with NSS behind your back.

At this point you're probably wondering what the difference is (and why people would bother with the added dependency), so here's a freebie:

- PADL's pam_ldap module (`libpam-ldap`) isn't actively developed. Nothing new and interesting will ever happen with it.
- Lack of daemon comes with a price: there is no way for library to share connections or state. *Every* invocation of the library must spin up its own unique LDAP connection and tear it back down. The primary strength of `libpam-ldapd` (and sssd for that matter) are that the backend daemon can handle the actual LDAP connection and keep a running state regarding its reachability.
- `libpam-ldapd` has [at least one situational feature](https://serverfault.com/a/547169/152073) that is not present in either sssd or the other PAM module.

The inclusion of a daemon is more of a sticking point when you *are* using the NSS module, because every single program having to independently time out on reaching the LDAP server is less than ideal and why I envy every younger Linux admin who has never had to learn that the hard way.

So there you go: you can avoid NSS integration, and you can avoid the nslcd daemon depending on the module you choose. The implementation strategy is up to you.

Comment: When you say "It will only get referenced", which are you you referring to? `libpam-ldapd`?  Also, you say "The latter" and then say "not `libnss-ldapd`", do you then mean the former?

Comment: I've edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, very concise otherwise. Covered my follow up questions generated by the answer.

Comment: It's a confusing mess: there are multiple implementations that have all claimed the name of `pam_ldap` and `pam_krb5` over the years. It's worth the time to save others the pain of researching it. :(

Comment: I've used `pam_ldap` years ago, that was when I thought pam was just a fancy way to configure user authentication backends. I followed a howto and that was the end of it. As my development role is broadening to cover more sysadmin tasks I'm learning pam can be used for a great deal more, and I want to try to use it more often.