# The differences between libpam-ldap and libpam-ldapd, included packages and modules?

Tags: ldap, pam, nss, pam-ldap

May I ask what's the differences between libpam-ldap and libpam-ldapd when it comes to included packages and modules?

As i understand is nss-pam-ldapd the project of libpam-ldapd, which is an improvement of nss_ldap. So, is nss_ldap the same as libpam-ldap or is it just the NSS which is included in the libpam-ldap package which as been improved, and everything else is the same?

Trying to write a report, but cannot understand what's included in those two packages, especially in libpam-ldap.

Comment: We generally frown on requests to perform academic research for others, but I'll grant you that this is an extremely dense topic to break into. This answer should give you what you need: http://serverfault.com/a/665441/152073

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link, it did answer several of my questions. However, why does libpam-ldap package include a package which is named the same as itself "libpam-ldap", and that is the same for libpam-ldapd?

E.g: libpam-ldapd includes: ldap-utils, libnss-ldapd, libpam-ldapd, nscd and nslcd. I think it's so strange that it includes a package which is named the same. 

The explanation for that included libpam-ldapd package is: "This is a PAM module which provides password management, authorization and authentication based on credentials stored in an LDAP-server".

Comment: Just to make sure I analyze this correctly, what OS distro are you working with?

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to mention that. We use Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: [This](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpam-ldap) is the list of dependencies for libpam-ldap in 14.04, and all I'm seeing is suggestions for libpam-ldapd or libnss-ldap. Neither are hard dependencies, and neither duplicate the name of the package itself as you're suggesting here. Make sure you're not getting these package names mixed up, because it's very easy to do.

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot for your help, the first link you sent was very helpful. I don't think this thread is interesting for anyone besides me, so I will delete it very soon.

Comment: No need, I have it flagged as a duplicate and things will probably take their course. Please upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks!